# C++ short* to VARIANT_BOOL*

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boolean, variant

I have a function that expects a `short*` as an argument.
I would need to convert this to a `VARIANT_BOOL*`.
Can anybody tell me a reliable way to do this?

I can even pass the `VARIANT_BOOL*` to the function, but then the `VARIANT_BOOL*` is not filled with the correct value.

Thank you very much for the help!

```
STDMETHODIMP CWrapper::get_IsOpen(VARIANT_BOOL* uIsOpen, LONG* pVal)
{
    if (_c)
    {
        *pVal=_c->IsOpen(uIsOpen); //_c->IsOpen expects short* as argument
        return S_OK;
    }
    else
    {
        return S_FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out [BOOL vs. VARIANT_BOOL vs. BOOLEAN vs. bool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/12/22/329884.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`VARIANT_BOOL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237864.aspx) is defined as:

```
typedef short VARIANT_BOOL;
```

So if you want to pass a `VARIANT_BOOL` to a function that takes a `short*`, you need to take its address using `&`. If you want turn the `short` that a `short*` points at into a `VARIANT_BOOL`, you need to perform indirection using `*`.

```
VARIANT_BOOL vb = VARIANT_TRUE;

short* sp = &vb; // VARIANT_BOOL to short*

VARIANT_BOOL vb2 = *sp; // short8 to VARIANT_BOOL
```

Comment: Thank you! I have added my code to the posting. Could you perhaps show me how I should do it exactely now that you see how I do it?

Comment: @tmighty You are doing it correctly. `VARIANT_BOOL*` and `short*` are the same thing.

Comment: I had to add   //VARIANT_BOOL TO BOOL
  *uIsOpen *= -1; to make it work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Put the VARIANT_BOOL in a short, call the function, put the short back into the VARIANT_BOOL.